# How can fix issue Not Enough Memory Upload Image Filemanager Responsive

Tags: php

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb5uJ.png)

my problem is can't upload image with filemanageresponsive

 i try upload image with size 32kb

How to fix my problem, 
i try with this

- https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager/issues/330
- resize upload size in php.ini = upload_max_filesize = 20MB

its not yet to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check post_max_size in php.ini.
It must be larger than file max size, i.e larger than 32kb in your case.